# Randomizing order of what appears in the second and third columns

Tags: unix, awk, sed

If I have a text file in the following format, where the field separator is , and the text delimiter is '  This is how it looks if opened in a text editor such as gedit

```
'not','here and stuff','overthere other stuff not blah'
'cookies','no cookies in the cookie jar','I must have coffie'
'what','do you want','I'm busy'
'more,working on stuff','tired of owrking on stuff'
'ok','I got a new mugg','I have no clothes'
'maybe','this is','enough sample input'
```

and I want to shuffle the order of what appears in $2 and $3 so that it's random, but I want to leave $1 alone and I want to make sure that everything that appears on a given line stays on that line, how would I do this?

Something like `sort --random-sort` works to randomize the order of the lines but what about the order of what appears in the second and third columns?

sample output (fake randomized by me)

```
'not','overthere other stuff not blah','here and stuff'
'cookies','no cookies in the cookie jar','I must have coffie'
'what','I'm busy','do you want'
'more','tired of owrking on stuff','working on stuff'
'ok','I got a new mugg','I have no clothes'
'maybe','enough sample input','this is'
```

Comment: you want the pair of `$2` and `$3` stay together or just shuffle two sets of them?

Comment: to shuffle the order that the pair of $2 and $3 appear in the given line.

Comment: Your sample input has `'more,working on stuff'` without `'` around the comma, while your sample output has `'more'`...`,'working on stuff'` with `'`. How come?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in awk seems to work as you want:

```
awk -F ',' -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {srand(seed); OFS=","} {if (int(rand()*100) % 2 == 0)print $1,$2,$3; else print $1,$3,$2 }'
```

We first tell awk the delimiter is "," via `-F','`

We then get a random seed to generate the random numbers via `-v seed=$RANDOM`

In the begin block, we seed our random number and make the OFS "," via `BEGIN {srand(seed); OFS=","}`

We then get a random number, make it an integer and then see if its modulo 2 is 0.  If so, print the normal order, otherwise switch the order.

Based on the commment of this not working, here's some example input and output:

```
~$ cat testawk.txt
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Output:

```
~$ awk -F ',' -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {srand(seed); OFS=","} {if (int(rand()*100) % 2 == 0)print $1,$2,$3; else print $1,$3,$2 }' testawk.txt
    1,2,3
    1,2,3
    1,2,3
    1,2,3
    1,3,2
    1,2,3
    1,3,2
    1,2,3
    1,2,3
    1,3,2
```

And here's another run using your data:

```
~$ cat testawk2.txt
not,here and stuff,overthere other stuff not blah
cookies,no cookies in the cookie jar,I must have coffie
what,do you want,I'm busy
more,working on stuff,tired of owrking on stuff
ok,I got a new mugg,I have no clothes
maybe,this is,enough sample input



~$ awk -F ',' -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {srand(seed); OFS=","} {if (int(rand()*100) % 2 == 0)print $1,$2,$3; else print $1,$3,$2 }' testawk2.txt
not,here and stuff,overthere other stuff not blah
cookies,no cookies in the cookie jar,I must have coffie
what,I'm busy,do you want
more,tired of owrking on stuff,working on stuff
ok,I got a new mugg,I have no clothes
maybe,this is,enough sample input
```

And another run to demonstrate that it will be different each time:

```
~$ awk -F ',' -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {srand(seed); OFS=","} {if (int(rand()*100) % 2 == 0)print $1,$2,$3; else print $1,$3,$2 }' testawk2.txt
not,overthere other stuff not blah,here and stuff
cookies,no cookies in the cookie jar,I must have coffie
what,do you want,I'm busy
more,working on stuff,tired of owrking on stuff
ok,I got a new mugg,I have no clothes
maybe,this is,enough sample input
```

Comment: this does not seem to do that task

Comment: I've added examples of this seeming to work on sample data and your example data.  Do you have more detail on why this is not working for you?

Comment: yea, I get strange output, maybe this will help. I stated the field separator was , and the text delimiter was '      So if you open the file in a text editor it's in this format: `'word','sentence here and stuff','sentenceanother here more'`

Comment: So this is a partially quoted CSV file using single quotes instead of double quotes?  In that case more accurate example data would be helpful, as it seems your example does not match your use case.  Given your updated comment example, the code should still work, so I'm imagining you have comma's within some fields causing issues.  

In dealing with quoted CSV's, if you're using a newer version of awk, the FPAT variable may be useful to you - https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Comment: if a field is in '' then commas inside the '' should be ignored correct?

Comment: Not by default in Awk.  Awk is very simplistic in its view of splitting fields, if you tell it to split on comma's, it breaks out fields based on every comma, irrespective of any other characters.   This is why I mentioned the GAWK feature of FPAT, in which you describe what a field is, rather than what a delimiter is.

Comment: You don't need to pass an argument to `srand()`, in fact you're better off not doing so as by default it'll use the current date+time as it's seed value so that WILL be different than any previous value.

Comment: Touche, though I'm going to leave my code as is since changing it wouldn't leave the true output and it still works in this simple case.